# Passing complex parameter to jsp include

Tags: java, jsp, include

In my main jsp I am including another jsp to display a fragment of the page.  I need to pass a parameter to this include:

I know about:

```
<jsp:param name="param2" value="value2" />
```

My problem is that the value needs to be a complicated string (which probably needs to be escaped) (e.g. `<a href="something?param=aParam&..."> ..`).  In other words, the value needs to be a bit of markup itself.  What is the proper way to get the string over to the include without breaking the markup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by complex (or complicated), but I don't think JSP include was meant to pass any [POJO](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PlainOldJavaObject) aside from [scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28computing%29) values like strings and numbers. Try putting the parameter into request or session scope.